# HTML button element in React component showing Typescript error "Property 'disabled' does not exist on type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to disable a submit button in React when a prop "processing" is true, but the TypeScript compiler is throwing an error.

The component:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

interface SubmitButtonProps {
    processing: boolean;
}

const SubmitButton: FunctionComponent<SubmitButtonProps> = (props) => {
    const { processing } = props;
    return (
        <button
            className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            type="submit"
            aria-disabled={processing}
            disabled={processing}
        >
            {processing ? 'Processing' : 'Open'}
        </button>
    );
};

export default SubmitButton;
```

The error:

```
Type '{ children: string; className: string; type: string; "aria-disabled": boolean; disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'
Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.  TS2322
```

Edit:
This is the component for the form element that the submit button is being used in:

```
import React, { Component, FormEvent } from 'react';
import CSVLoader from '../../modules/csv-loader';
import { IFile } from '../../types';
import FileInput from './FileInput';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton';

interface IState {
    processing: boolean;
    fileTextContent: string;
    fileName: string;
}

interface IProps {
    onChange: (data: IFile) => void;
}

class FileSelector extends Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { processing: false, fileTextContent: '', fileName: '' };
    }
    async handleAttachFile(e: FormEvent): Promise<void> {
        const { files } = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const file = files?.item(0);
        const fileText = await file?.text();
        const fileName = file?.name;
        this.setState({
            fileTextContent: fileText ?? '',
            fileName: fileName ?? 'untitled',
        });
    }
    async process(e: FormEvent): Promise<void> {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ processing: true });
        const data = await CSVLoader(
            this.state.fileName,
            this.state.fileTextContent
        );
        this.props.onChange(data);
    }

    render() {
        const { processing } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.process(e)}>
                    <FileInput onAttachFile={(e) => this.handleAttachFile(e)} />
                    <div className="mb-3 text-end">
                        <SubmitButton processing={processing} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FileSelector;
```

The button was originally inside this component and was throwing the same error before I moved it to its own component to try and isolate the problem.

Edit 2:
It seems to be a configuration issue somehwere. Mousing over a  in VSCode shows its type as
"(property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.button: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes, HTMLAnchorElement>"

Comment: It is likely the problem is outside of this component. Could you post the code where this `SubmitButton` is used?

Comment: I tried your code, and can't see that it fails

Comment: This error `Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'` seems to indicate you are trying to disable an `<a>` tag, but your code clearly uses a `<button>` tag. I'm not sure how that's possible...

Comment: Just to double check, when you remove `<SubmitButton processing={processing} />` from `FileSelector`, the error goes away?

Comment: @HanchenJiang yes, and it also goes away if I remove the disabled attribute from the button.

Comment: This seems weird. I suggest create a minimum runnalbe example that has the same problem. I don't see anything that can produce this error based on posted code.

Comment: It does seem to be something elsewhere in the project since I tried to disable a button in a different component and it gives the same error.